# Google Cloud Datastore Query's

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nosql

Trying to locate data based on its Name/ID field which is auto generated within Google cloud. I want to be able to update the given entity, however I am finding it hard to work with the data formatting. I have a list of data with a button which says 'Update" when clicking the update it gives the Unique Name/ID of that entity, however i cannot seem to find a method of also pulling the information associated with that Name/ID within google cloud.

[Table with data in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThbIB.png)

[Data inside google cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToPZt.png)

[Unique ID located but struggling to pull the other data based on that ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g72Oe.png)

```
def updateSong():

    songID = request.form['Update']
    # songQuery = datastore_client.query(kind="Song")
    # songs = list(songQuery.fetch())

    query = datastore_client.query(kind='Song', ancestor=songID)
    songData = query.fetch()

    print(songData)

    id_token = request.cookies.get("token")
    error_message = None

    if id_token:
        try:

            user_data = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(
                id_token, firebase_request_adapter)

        except ValueError as exc:
            error_message = str(exc)
    
    return render_template('UpdateSong.html', user_data=user_data, error_message=error_message, songID=songID)
```

Is there not a method of querying the song ID to then be able to use it as such:

```
song['Title'] = song title
```

Comment: but you don't have the variable ```song```. What you have is ```songData```. Are you saying ```songData['Title'] = song title``` doesn't work?

Comment: @NoCommandLine Song is the name of the Datastore Kind variable (Poor naming i know). I'm having issues retrieving the data for one song (Title, Artist, Quantity, Price) through the use of its Name/ID which is auto-generated through google cloud (used as songID taken from the list of songs). Is there a way i can call one instance from the entity 'Song' to then break down later in a form for the user to change then update?

Comment: @NoCommandLine songData['Title'] only works when i have it in a loop iterating through all the different datapoints

Comment: when you do ```fetch()```, you get a sequence. You can try ```songData = list(query.fetch(1))[0]``` which means fetch only 1 result, convert it to a list (so you can access it), then pick the first item in that list

Comment: @NoCommandLine It should only retrieve one song as each song has its own unique ID but I'm not sure my query is correct for retrieving one item via Name/ID (see the query where im passing the ID as ancestor not sure this is the correct method). I just need to preload the data into the update song page so the user can edit it then click update where i'll use the update function to push the changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    query = datastore_client.query()
    query.key_filter(datastore_client.key('Song', songID))
    song = list(query.fetch())
```

**Source:** https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datastore/query.html#Query.key_filter

Comment: Not sure it retrieves anything, I know the songID is correct too

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by - not sure it retrieves anything. It either retrieve its or it doesn't. If it gives an error, let's know the error